# PowerTransform inverse_transform not inverting accurately

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm testing PowerTransform inverse_transform for skewed datasets but I'm not getting the column values back accurately.

Why isnt val TRUE?

```
from numpy.random import randn
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
import pandas as pd


col1 = pd.Series([1 for i in range(70)] + [10, 20, 30])
col2 = pd.Series(randn(73), name='col')
df = pd.concat([col2, col1], axis=1)

col1_np = col1.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
label_regression_transform = PowerTransformer()
data_label_trans = label_regression_transform.fit_transform(col1_np)
inv_trans = label_regression_transform.inverse_transform(data_label_trans)
val = np.allclose(inv_trans, col1_np)
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's `allclose` method tests if two arays are element-wise equal **within a tolerance**. The default parameters are `rtol=1e-05` for relative tolerance and `atol=1e-08` for absolute tolerance (see the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)).

However, check the difference between your original and transformed values, e.g. the last one:

```py
print(col1_np[-1]) # output: [30]
print(inv_trans[-1]) # output: [27.67403189]
```

`PowerTransformer` cannot always reproduce the exact original value due to limitations in floating point precision. Apparently, `allclose` will therefore (correctly) return `False` with the default parameters.

So, it is not a bug of `PowerTransformer` or anything in that regard. What you could do is to adjust the tolerance according to your needs, for example:

```py
val = np.allclose(inv_trans, col1_np, rtol=0.1) # val == True
```